# функция выдает none

Tags: python-3.x

Создать функцию, которая будет принимать вещественное число и представлять его в виде процентов, также будет принимать ещё один необязательный параметр, который будет указывать на количество цифр после запятой в числе процентов. Если этот параметр отсутствует, то пусть функция округляет результат до целого процента.

```
percent(0.0123) == "1%"
percent(0.0123, 0) == "1%"
percent(0.0123, 1) == "1.2%"
percent(0.0123, 10) == "1.23%"
```

наш код:

```
def percent(share, round_digits = 0):
    p = (float(share*100))
    if round_digits:
        round_p = round(p, round_digits)
        return (round_p,'%')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return в Вашем коде работает только внутри if. Если round_digits равно 0, то функция не заходит в условие и возвращает None, по стандарту.

Напишите

```py
if round_digits:
    round_p = round(p, round_digits)
    return str(round_p) + '%'
else:
    return str(int(p)) + '%'
```

Comment: большое спасибо, всё получилось!